# how to make calendar to work with gotoDate function with filter and remains on same

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i have 3 filter i used session there and i don't understand how it can be done

```
    $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {    
        var b = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
        var test = b.format('L');
        alert(test);
     });
    /* Next button click ... */

    $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
            var b = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
            var test = b.format('L');
            alert(test);                
        });


    });
```

this gives me first date of every month how i can use this with goto function so that if  i am on october month and select name from user filter it doesnot redirect me on current month instead of that remains on that

please help 
i have used `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', "2016-10");`
then it always display this month now i want if i select name from filter then it remains on that month not redirect on current month 
i used `defaultDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>'`,

Comment: can you share your full code !

Comment: ya sure, see my edited question

Comment: so you mean to tell that when you select filter, the date is getting changed ?

Comment: yes i don't want that

Comment: in your case  defaultDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>', when ever you change the filter the page is submitted and refreshed.  here calendar is also getting reinitialized. you check the value of date("Y-m-d") . if result of <?=date("Y-m-d")?> is current month then full calendar will display the resulted date.

Comment: yes i know that please tell me what do to do for  this

Comment: when you get date for first time you store into a localstorage and when page reloads check if loacalstorage has value or not. if it has value then set the default value as stored value,  else set the default value has '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>'

Comment: i don't know it can ba done  u make change in my code please ..

Comment: okay i cant edit it fully , i can give  you work around , check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/728/

Comment: it still redirecting me on current month and display storedDate as the date variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129777/discussion-between-meow-and-raki).